# _ga has been rejected for invalid domain issue in firefox

Tags: firefox, google-analytics

I'm using The ga() command queue with tracking code  and cookie_domain in my script as specified here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs#the_google_analytics_tag

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', '<site_name>');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

But, when I open my Page site with Firefox browser, the console logs the following warning messages:

```
Cookie “_ga” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Cookie “_gid” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Cookie “_ga” has been rejected for invalid domain. 
Cookie “_gid” has been rejected for invalid domain.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The answer rather depends on the value for "<site_name>" which you do not show - what is supposed to go there is the domain on which the cookie is set. Setting it to "auto" (or omit it) is the safe choice, else you need to make sure that the value is the hostname of the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this kind of configuration:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', { 'cookieFlags': 'SameSite=None; Secure' });
```

For more details '**Cookies and User Identification**': https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id

Comment: Their new script looks like:  gtag('config', 'G-xxxx');, no 'create'.

Comment: New script is for GA4, not UA (that is the snippet in the question).

Answer (score -1):

I found this article

https://www.tinstar.co.uk/studio-blog/some-cookies-are-misusing-the-recommended-samesite-attribute-how-to-fix/

It suggests using:

```
{cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure'}
```

So using the key `cookie_flags` rather than `cookieFlags`

This fixed the samesite issue on my site whereas the `cookieFlags` did not.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using GA4 and added the following:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', { 'cookieFlags': 'SameSite=None; Secure' });
```

Still the same error in FF while fine in Chrome & Edge. Any other possibilities that I can check?